# Rotman's Introduction to the Theory of Groups Exercise 1.27

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

[image]

My try for (i) $G = \{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$. If $n$ is even, an odd number of $a_j \ne e$ must have its inverse among the $a_j\ne 0$, then at least one $a_j\ne 0$ must be its own inverse, which contradicts the hypothesis. Thus $n$ must be odd. Thus each $a_j\ne 0$ is multiplied by its inverse in $a_1*a_2*\cdots*a_n$ so it equals $e*e = e$.

But I think something must be wrong with this proof because in (ii), using the hint, we would have that $\mathbb{Z}_p-\{0\} = \{1,\dots, p-1\}$ is a group satisfying the hypothesis in (i) with $n = p-1$ even for most $p$. Also, this won't lead to the answer because we would have $[(p-1)!] = [1]$ which leads to $(p-1)!\equiv_p 1$ and $1$ isn't equivalent to $-1\mod{p}$ for all $p$ prime.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it is better to *describe* your question in the title (e.g. "Abelian groups of odd order and the proof of Wilson's theorem"), rather than just stating the place you found it. (Of course, you can do both!) I suspect that more people will look at your questions then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. Part (i) doesn't apply *directly* because $(-1)^2 = 1$ but you can still apply the same ideas. Every element $a$ which is not equal to $1$ or $-1$ has an inverse which is distinct from $a$ (think about why this is). So in evaluating $(p - 1)!$, all the terms cancel except $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Now that you clarified that, I think the set $\{[1],[2],...,[p-2]\}$ is a group satisfying the conditions in (i) so $[(p-2)!] = [1]$ by (i), which multipliying by [p-1] gives Wilson's Theorem. Is that correct?

Comment: @AnalyticHarmony It's not a group. For instance if $p = 5$ then $2 * 2 = p - 1$ so it isn't closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 6):

**Lemma.**
*(Part 3 here is the most relevant, see the corollary below.)*
Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Denote $G=\{g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n\}$, and let $b$ be the product of all its elements, i.e., $b=g_1\cdot g_2\cdot \ldots\cdot g_n$. Thus:

1. $b^2=e$.
2. $H=\{x\in G\mid x^2=e\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
3. If there is exactly one an element in $G$ of order $2$, it's $b$.
4. If there is more than one element in $G$ of order $2$, $b=e$.

*Proof.*

1. Since every element in $G$ has its inverse, we can also write $G=\{g_1^{-1},g_2^{-1},\ldots,g_n^{-1}\}$. Therefore $b$ is also
   $$b=g_1\cdot g_2\cdot \ldots \cdot g_n=g_1^{-1}\cdot g_2^{-1}\cdot \ldots \cdot g_n^{-1}.$$
   Now, since $G$ is abelian, we can calculate $b^2$ as:
   $$b^2=g_1 g_2 \ldots g_n g_1^{-1} g_2^{-1} \ldots g_n^{-1}=(g_1 g_1^{-1})( g_2 g_2^{-1})\ldots(g_n g_n^{-1})=e.$$
2. It is easy to check that if $a^2=b^2=e$, using the fact that $G$ is abelian, that $(ab)^2=e$ and $a^{-1}=b^{-1}=e$ too. $e^2=e$ too, therefore $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, as it's nonempty and closed under product and inverse.
3. If $x\in G$ is the only element of order $2$, it is therefore the only element that is the inverse of itself, so we can write
   $$b=g_1 g_2\ldots g_n=e\cdot x\cdot \prod_{g\in G \textbf{ s.t. }   o(g) > 2} gg^{-1}=x.$$
4. For $H\le G$ as before, denote $H=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r\}$. It is left to the reader to verify that it is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$, the field with two elements, with $e=\vec{0}$ and every element being the additive inverse of itself. If $B=(v_1,\ldots ,v_m)$ is a basis for $H$, where $m=\log_{2} {r}$ (where $m\ge3$ from our assumption). There are $2^{m-1}$ elements such that their $i$'th component (in respect to the basis $B$) is $0$, and therefore an even number of elements with their $i$'th component being $1$. Convince yourself that the sum (or any group action, i.e., their sum as vectors) of all elements of $H$ is $\vec{0}$, as it's $0$ in every component. □

**Corollary: Wilson's Theorem.**
Let $p$ be a prime. So $p$ divides $(p-1)!+1$.

*Proof.* Consider $\mathbb{F}_p^*$, the multiplicative group of the field with $p$ elements. Note that it has $p-1$ elements. Since the polynomial $x^2-1$ has at most $2$ roots over the field $\mathbb{F}_p$, up to two elements $x\in \mathbb{F}_p^*$ might satisfy $x^2=1$. The number $1$ (or $1_{\mathbb{F}_p}$) satisfies this equation, and so does $-1$ (wich, by assuming $p>2$, are different elements). Since $1$ is of order $1$, $-1$ is the only element of order $2$. From part 3 of the lemma we obtain that the product of all elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is $b=-1$, therefore we have
$$1\cdot 2\cdot \ldots \cdot (p-1)=-1,$$
and, equivalently:
$$(p-1)!+1\equiv 0 \mod(p).$$ □

Answer (score 1):

My approach is quite simple:
Let $s = g_{1}g_{2}...g_{n}$.

By multiplying s by the inverse of each element we should get the identity $e$, since G is abelian.

Consider the group homomorphism: 
$$\phi: G \rightarrow G, \phi(g) = g^{-1}$$
You can verify that this is indeed a bijection.

Thus $\phi(G) = G$, which is equivalent to saying that taking the inverse of each element of $G$ is the same group $G$.

$$s =g^{-1}_{1}g^{-1}_{2}...g^{-1}_{n}$$
$$sg^{-1}_{1}g^{-1}_{2}...g^{-1}_{n} = 1$$
$$s^{2} = 1$$.

Since we assumed $G$ has no elements of order 2, which is the same as saying no $g \in G-\{1\}$ satisfies $g^{2} = 1$, thus $s=1$.